# Alexa indexing browsing history?

Tags: alexa

We have this test.php sitting around in a forgotten folder. It is a script which just sends an email to our site admin.

We never had a page linking to it. It is not indexed by Google. It does not exist in the Internet Archive Wayback Machine.

But every now and then it gets crawled by ia_archiver.

I wonder how it got indexed. Could it be because of the Alexa toolbar installed on our computer? Does Alexa index our personal browsing history?

Comment: Obviously your browser activity is used, as that's how they gather their data. Is what you're asking whether they do this in some way that leaves the information personally identifiable, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Alexa exists only because it indexes and finds content by using software installed on user's computers. So the answer to your question is yes.